# $f'$ strictly increases and $f'(c)=0$. There exist $x_1 < c < x_2$ such that $f'(c)=\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2 - x_1}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-writing, proof-verification

**Question:**
Let $f$ be continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$. Assume that $f'$ is strictly increasing. Show that for any $c\in(a,b)$ such that $f'(c)=0$, there exist $x_1, x_2 \in [a,b], x_1 < c < x_2$ such that $f'(c)=\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2 - x_1}$.

**What I've done:**
We argue by contradiction. Assume that for all $x_1<c<x_2$, we have $f'(c) \ne \frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2 - x_1}$. Without losing generality, we assume that $f'(c) < \frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2 - x_1}$.

If we take limit on both side, we have

$\displaystyle \lim_{x_2 \to x_1} f'(c) \le \lim_{x_2\to x_1}\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2 - x_1} $. (*I am not sure if this step is correct or make any sense*)

So we have $f'(c) \le f'(x_1)$. But since $f'$ is strictly increasing, and we know that $x_1<c$, so this cannot be the case. Contradiction.

Comment: Your $c$ is the only point that satisfies $f'(c)=0.$ If you fix $x_1$ and consider $x_2\to x_1$ then, since $x_1<c$ there is a moment where $x_2<c.$ So, you can't get a contradiction from this, because you are assuming $x_2>c.$

Comment: Yeah that's what I suspected. So do you have any idea how I should approach this problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f'$ is strictly increasing and $f'(c)=0$ we have that $f'<0$ on $(a,c)$ and $f'>0$ on $(c,b).$ Consider the values $f(a),f(b).$ If $f(a)=f(b)$ we have done, because $f'(c)=0=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}.$ In other case, without lost of generality, assume $f(a)<f(b).$ Since $c$ is a global minimum of $f$ on $[a,b]$ we have $f(c)<f(a)<f(b).$ It is a consequence of the intermediate value theorem that there exists $d\in (c,b)$ such that $f(d)=f(a),$ and thus  $f'(c)=0=\frac{f(d)-f(a)}{d-a}.$

Comment: Why is $c$ a minimum of $f$ on $[a,b]$?

Comment: Since on $(a,c)$ you have $f'<0$ (note that $f'$ is strictly increasing and $f'(c)=0$) $f$ is decreasing on $[a,c]$ and on $(c,b)$ $f'>0$ (again $f'$ is strictly increasing and $f'(c)=0$) $f$ is increasing on $[c,b].$ So, at $x=c,$ $f$ changes from be decreasing to be increasing, and thus $x=c$ must be a global minimum.